# How to add multiple products at the same time in prestashop cart using PHP?

Tags: php, prestashop

Last week I started develop module on prestoshop. I have made image upload module. When images are uploaded and processed, I need add them to cart using PHP. Images are saved in upload directory, and info about them in session, not in DB. Only registered customers can make upload. It is posters printing requests online servise. I have stuck at this point. I tried dig in core files, but it was waste of time. Documentation about core development are weak. How can I add product (image) to cart, who not exist in DB?

Comment: What's the existing code? How is the shopping cart handled? What have you tried?

Comment: Session contains image name, copy quantity, and url to uploaded image and image cost. I have tried use CartController, where $cartController = new CartControllerCore(); and to call init with parameters.